# GWT - extract text in between two characters

Tags: java, regex, gwt, substring

In GWT i have a servlet that returns an image from the database to the client. I need to extract out part of the string to properly show the image. What is returned in chrome, firefox, and IE has a slash in the src part. Ex: String s = "src=\""; Which is not visible in the string below. Maybe the slash is adding more parentheses around the http string. Im not sure?

```
  what is returned in those 3 browsers is = <img style="-webkit-user-select: none;" src="http://localhost:8080/dashboardmanager/downloadfile?entityId=4886">
```

EDGE browser doesn't have the slash in the src so my method to extract the image doesnt work in edge

**What edge returns:**

```
String edge = "<img src=”http://localhost:8080/dashboardmanager/downloadfile?entityId=4886”>";
```

Problem: I need to extract the string below.

```
http://localhost:8080/dashboardmanager/downloadfile?entityId=4886
```

either with src= or src=\

What I tried and works with the browsers that return without the parentheses "src=\":

```
String s = "src=\"";
int index = returned.indexOf(s) + s.length();
image.setUrl(returned.substring(index, returned.indexOf("\"", index + 1)));
```

But fails to work in EDGE because it doesnt return a slash

I do not have access to Pattern, and matcher in GWT.

How can i extract and keep in mind the entityId number will change 
http://localhost:8080/dashboardmanager/downloadfile?entityId=4886

out of **what is returned** string above?

**EDIT:**

I need a generic way to extract out http://localhost:8080/dashboardmanager/downloadfile?entityId=4886

When the string might look like this both ways.

```
String edge = "<img src=”http://localhost:8080/dashboardmanager/downloadfile?entityId=4886”>";

3 browsers is = <img style="-webkit-user-select: none;" src="http://localhost:8080/dashboardmanager/downloadfile?entityId=4886">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String toParse = "<img style=\"-webkit-user-select: none;\" src=\"http://localhost:8080/dashboardmanager/downloadfile?entityId=4886\">";    
        String delimiter = "src=\"";
        int index = toParse.indexOf(delimiter) + delimiter.length();
        System.out.println(toParse.substring(index, toParse.length()).split("\"")[0]);      
    }
```

Comment: in edge its String toParse = "<img src=”http://localhost:8080/dashboardmanager/downloadfile?entityId=4886”>"; I need a way to extract the http part. irregardless of how the string starts.

Comment: Example provided still works if you change the toParse declaration for:
        String toParse = "<img src=\"http://localhost:8080/dashboardmanager/downloadfile?entityId=4886\">";

Comment: no, the one you posted above has a slash but shouldnt and wont have one. The first one has a slash and the second one doesnt.  example String toParse = "<img src="localhost:8080/dashboardmanager/downloadfile?entityId=4886">";

Comment: will your example work with a slash and without a slash?

Comment: Slashes are only there to escape the double-quote in the string declaration. So yes, it will.

Comment: okay, i am going tocheck it out and get back to you. If it works i will accept your answer in about an hour. Thanks for helping so far.